# Gap in primes(Codewars) - out of time

Tags: python

Question:
The prime numbers are not regularly spaced. For example from 2 to 3 the gap is 1. From 3 to 5 the gap is 2. From 7 to 11 it is 4. Between 2 and 50 we have the following pairs of 2-gaps primes: 3-5, 5-7, 11-13, 17-19, 29-31, 41-43

A prime gap of length n is a run of n-1 consecutive composite numbers between two successive primes (see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html).

We will write a function gap with parameters:

g (integer >= 2) which indicates the gap we are looking for

m (integer > 2) which gives the start of the search (m inclusive)

n (integer >= m) which gives the end of the search (n inclusive)

n won't go beyond 1100000.

In the example above gap(2, 3, 50) will return [3, 5] or (3, 5) or {3, 5} which is the first pair between 3 and 50 with a 2-gap.

So this function should return the first pair of two prime numbers spaced with a gap of g between the limits m, n if these numbers exist otherwise `nil or null or None or Nothing (or ... depending on the language).

```
# My attempt
def gap(g, m, n):
    prime = [True for _ in range(n+1)]
    p = 2
    
    while (p*p <= n):
        if prime[p]:
            for i in range(p*p, n+1, p):
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1
        
    nums = [i for i, T in enumerate(prime) if T and i>m]
    
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i+1] - nums[i] == g:
            return [nums[i], nums[i+1]]
        
    else: return
```

My function works fine in smaller numbers, but when it comes to more than 6 digits it ran out of time. Where could I improve my code?

Answer (score 1):

You could eliminate the whole second part with the nums list by keeping track of the distance between primes in your sieve of Eratosthenes logic. Also, you could initialize you primes list with multiples of two already discarded, then step by two to check primes after 2 and the rule of 6 after 5.

You can update the the multiples of primes with

```
primes[p*p::2*p] = [False]*len(range(p*p,len(primes),2*p))
```

instead of a for loop.

Here's what the optimized version could look like:

```
def gap(g, m, n):
    isPrime = [False,False,True]+[True,False]*(n//2)
    prev,p,inc = 2,3,2    
    while p<=n:
        if isPrime[p]:
            isPrime[p*p::2*p] = [False]*len(range(p*p,len(isPrime),2*p))
            if prev>=m and p-prev == g:
                return prev,p
            prev = p
        p,inc = p+inc,2 if p<5 else (6-inc)
```

Personally, I would approach this a little differently.  I would first create a generator function that produces primes.  Then I would use that generator function to get primes and track the differences from one to the next and return the first eligible pair:

```
def primeGen(maxPrime):   # primes generator, up to maxPrime
    skip = dict()
    yield 2
    p = 1
    while p<=maxPrime:
        p += 2
        if p not in skip:
            yield p
            if p*p<maxPrime: skip[p*p] = 2*p
            continue
        step = skip.pop(p)
        mult = p + step
        while mult in skip: mult += step
        skip[mult] = step

def primeGap(g,m,n):
    previous = None
    for prime in primeGen(n):
        if prime<m: continue
        if previous and prime-previous == g:
            return previous,prime
        previous = prime
```

*Note that this is slower (2x) than the sieve when the gap is not found early (before n/4) so you should stick with the optimized gap() function if execution time is constrained*

Output:

```
print(primeGap(2,3,50))        # (3,5)
print(primeGap(4,3,50))        # (7,11)
print(primeGap(6,3,50))        # (23,29)
print(primeGap(8,1000,2000))   # (1109, 1117)     
print(primeGap(48,1,1100000))  # (28229, 28277)    6.5 milliseconds
print(primeGap(100,1,1100000)) # (396733, 396833) 79.5 milliseconds
```

**[EDIT]** work around for timeout ...

It seems the issue is with regenerating primes on every test.  If you create a list of primes in a global variable (outside the function) and use it for the gap search in the function, then you won't get the timeout.

```
primes   = [2]     
maxPrime = 1100000
isPrime = [False,False,True]+[True,False]*(maxPrime//2)
p,inc = 3,2    
while p<=maxPrime:
    if isPrime[p]:
        primes.append(p)
        isPrime[p*p::2*p] = [False]*len(range(p*p,len(isPrime),2*p))
    p,inc = p+inc,2 if p<5 else (6-inc)

def gap(g, m, n):
    prev = None
    for p in primes:
        if p>n: break
        if p<m: continue
        if prev and p-prev == g: return [prev,p]
        prev = p
```

**[EDIT2]** even faster solution ...

Given that the expectation (or allowable approach) is to prepare global variables, we could go a step further and build a dictionary of prime lists keyed on the gaps.  Then the function could use a binary search for `m` in the list corresponding to `g` and find the result in logN time. This is at least 2x faster overall than the previous solution that does a sequential search through the primes. After setting up the dictionary, the gap() function returns results in 7 microseconds.

```
gaps    = dict()
maxPrime = 1100000
isPrime = [False,False,True]+[True,False]*(maxPrime//2)
prev,p,inc = 2,3,2    
while p<=maxPrime:
    if isPrime[p]:
        isPrime[p*p::2*p] = [False]*len(range(p*p,len(isPrime),2*p))
        gapFirst,gapNext = gaps.setdefault(p-prev,[[],[]])
        gapFirst.append(prev)
        gapNext.append(p)
        prev=p
    p,inc = p+inc,2 if p<5 else (6-inc)

from bisect import bisect_left
def gap(g, m, n):
    gapFirst,gapNext = gaps.get(g,[[],[]])     # pairs for gap of 'g'
    i = bisect_left(gapFirst,m)                # binary search, >= m
    if i < len(gapFirst) and gapNext[i] <= n:
        return [ gapFirst[i], gapNext[i] ]     # Found first gap in [m...n]
```

Comment: woah..both solution raise 'Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)'... hmm I'm speechless now. Is there any possibilities that slower internet cause this?! https://www.codewars.com/kata/561e9c843a2ef5a40c0000a4/train/python

Comment: There must be some issue with the server.  12000ms is 12 seconds execution time.  Even the worst case scenario (i.e. not finding a pair in primes up to 1100000, only takes 66 ms on my laptop, with the optimized gap() function).  It's unlikely to be an internet speed issue.

Comment: Yes I've tried with jupyter notebook, and everything works fine. I guess I'll just skip this one :(

Comment: Figured out a workaround to the Time Out issue, see EDIT to my answer. They must be doing several hundred tests for it to go beyond 12 seconds.

Comment: Wow this works, I still don't get it somehow. I guess I'll look into bisect library later :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your time limit is. A simple optimization, which nevertheless yields the same computational complexity is to avoid copying the prime numbers that you found to a new vector.

Using `prime`, you can iterate over the array using a "window" of length `g`. starting from `m`, you check whether m is a prime and whether `m + g` is a prime. If yes, then Bingo! Otherwise you move on to `m + 1`.

You can see that in the following code

```
import time

def original_gap(g, m, n):
    prime = [True for _ in range(n + 1)]
    p = 2

    while p * p <= n:
        if prime[p]:
            for i in range(p * p, n + 1, p):
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1

    nums = [i for i, T in enumerate(prime) if T and i >= m]

    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i + 1] - nums[i] == g:
            return [nums[i], nums[i + 1]]

    return

def new_gap(g, m, n):
    if g > n - m:
        return None

    prime = [True for _ in range(n + 1)]
    p = 2

    while p * p <= n:
        if prime[p]:
            for i in range(p * p, n + 1, p):
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1

    for index in range(m, n - g + 1):
        if prime[index] and prime[index + g]:
            return [index, index + g]

    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    print(new_gap(2, 3, 1100000))
    end = time.time()
    print("Time for 3-1100000 is: ", end - start)

    start = time.time()
    print(original_gap(2, 3, 1100000))
    end = time.time()
    print("Time for 3-1100000 is: ", end - start)
```